# How to use Dialog in Fragment class

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I would like to have my custom popup displayed in a fragment. Unfortunately, the Object dialog does not refer to the correct layout. How can I have it point to the correct layout? I hope someone can explain to me where the error is so that I can call it up.

```
public class UserFragmentBestell<Textview> extends Fragment {
    
        RecyclerView recyclerView;
        TextView notfound;
        Dialog epicDialog;
    
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_fragment_bestell, container, false);
            recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_scroll);
            notfound = view.findViewById(R.id.user_order_notfound);
            getBestellungen();
            epicDialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
    
            return view;
    
        }
    
        
    
        public void callAction(int pId) {
            System.out.println(pId);
            epicDialog.setContentView(R.layout.user_popup_order_overview);
            epicDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            Button btn_order_overview_finish = (Button) epicDialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_order_overview_finish);
            //System.out.println(bestellung.get(position).getBestellnummer());
            btn_order_overview_finish.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    epicDialog.dismiss();
                }
    
            });
            epicDialog.show();
        }
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs#DialogFragment) suggests that you should not instantiate a Dialog directly in your case use AlterDialog instead

```
   public void callAction(int pId){ // idk what you're doing with pid
    new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
     .setMessage("message") //set the message on the dialog
     .setView(R.layout.user_popup_order_overview) // set layout as view of this dialog
     .setNegativeButton("cancel",null) // pressing cancel will dismiss this dialog
      }).create().show() // create and show this dialog;
   }
```

have a good day

Answer (score 0):

As Abhinav suggested, you shouldn't instantiate a Dialog directly. Creating a class extending [DialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment.html) worked best for me. This way, when I create an instance of the class, I only need to call the `show()` method.

An example in Kotlin:

```
class UnsavedChangesDialogFragment(private val listener: DialogInteractions) : DialogFragment() {

    interface DialogInteractions {
        fun onPositiveBtnPressed()
        fun onNegativeBtnPressed()
    }

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        return activity?.let {
            val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(it)
            builder
                .setMessage(R.string.changes_dialog_title)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.changes_dialog_continue) { _, _ ->
                    listener.onPositiveBtnPressed()
                }
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.changes_dialog_back) {_, _ ->
                    listener.onNegativeBtnPressed()
                    dismiss()
                }

            builder.create()
        } ?: throw IllegalStateException("Activity cannot be null")
    }
}
```

You can easily decide what'll happen after pressing the positive or negative button by adding an interface. This way, each fragment, which the dialog will be used in, can take different actions after the user interacted with the dialog.